# Receive a ObjC constant in Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c

I like to use an ObjC constant in Swift.

IronSource ad network recommends to initialize a banner ad like so:

```
[IronSource loadBannerWithViewController:self size:ISBannerSize_SMART];
```

I use Swift and translate is like so:

```
IronSource.loadBanner(with: self, size: dont_know)
```

But for parameter ISBannerSize_SMART I don't know what to fill in as nothing works for me. ISBannerSize.ISBannerSize_SMART not working, ISBannerSize_SMART not working...

This is how the ObjC source looks like.

```
//
//  ISBannerSize.h
//  IronSource

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static NSString* const kSizeSmart = @"SMART";

#define ISBannerSize_SMART [[ISBannerSize alloc] initWithDescription:kSizeSmart width:0 height:0]

@interface ISBannerSize : NSObject
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ISBannerSize_SMART` is not a constant. It is a macro that expands to

```objectivec
[[ISBannerSize alloc] initWithDescription:kSizeSmart width:0 height:0]
```

[Such macros are not imported into Swift.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using-imported-c-macros-in-swift) Only simple macros that expand to a constant value like the following, are imported into Swift:

```objectivec
#define SOME_CONSTANT 3.14
```

So you would need to translate `[[ISBannerSize alloc] initWithDescription:kSizeSmart width:0 height:0]` into Swift, i.e. something like

```swift
ISBannerSize(description: kSizeSmart, width: 0, height: 0)
```

You can use this directly as the `size` parameter of `loadBanner`, or you can write an extension of `ISBannerSize`:

```swift
extension ISBannerSize {
    static var smart: ISBannerSize {
        ISBannerSize(description: kSizeSmart, width: 0, height: 0)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
IronSource.loadBanner(with: self, size: .smart)
```

Comment: Thats just great. Thanks!